# Why is the program header executable?

Tags: linux, elf

I used readelf on several binaries on my linux box and saw something that surprised me in the program headers. This eample is from the 'ld' utility, but it also occurs with anything I compile with gcc.

PHDR           0x000034 0x08048034 0x08048034 0x00120 0x00120 R E 0x4

This segment spans the entirety of the program headers. Why is is marked as executable? It doesn't contain machine code. But also, why is even this present in the headers? I don't really want it in my program image.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The PHDR pointing to the PHDRs tells the loader that the PHDRs themselves should be mapped to the process address space, in order to make them accessible to the program itself.

This is useful mainly for dynamic linking.

The reason the memory is marked as executable is because the PHDRs are smaller than one page, and live right next to the start of the executable code. If the permissions for the PHDRs were different from those of the program text, the linker would have to insert padding between them.

Comment: Is this at load time or at runtime? I guess if it's at runtime gcc may not be smart enough to figure out that no runtime library loading is being performed.

Comment: It also doesn't explain why this memory should be executable.

Comment: Any dynamic library the program is linked against could be replaced by a version that loads plugins dynamically, so a dynamically linked program will always be capable of loading shared objects during execution, so the PHDRs need to be present.

Comment: The memory is executable because the PHDRs are smaller than one page, and live right next to the start of the executable code. If the permissions for the PHDRs were different from those of the program text, the linker would have to insert padding between them.

Comment: Aha. This finally begins to make sense.

Comment: By the way, the GNU C library dynamically loads plugins for name resolution -- for example, if you have multicast DNS enabled on your system, all programs will load the mDNS resolver module when they need to look up a host name; thus, your program indeed uses the dynamic linker.

Comment: Immediately after the PHDR there is an INTERP that isn't executable and refers to a segment which is 13 bytes long in memory. Maybe it's being 'promoted' to  executable?
Edit: The INTERP is read-only.

Comment: That is interesting. I dimly remember the PHDRs being assigned virtual address space inside the linker script, while the INTERP segment is inserted by special code, so probably that is why the PHDRs inherit the *executable* flag from the text section they were generated in.

Answer (score 0):

The main File ELF headers are there to easily find the offset in the file where other sections are stored.  Then each subheader describes the data in it's section.

Main ELF header looks like this:

```
/* ELF File Header */
typedef struct
{
  unsigned char e_ident[EI_NIDENT];     /* Magic number and other info */
  Elf32_Half    e_type;                 /* Object file type */
  Elf32_Half    e_machine;              /* Architecture */
  Elf32_Word    e_version;              /* Object file version */
  Elf32_Addr    e_entry;                /* Entry point virtual address */
  Elf32_Off     e_phoff;                /* Program header table file offset */
  Elf32_Off     e_shoff;                /* Section header table file offset */
  Elf32_Word    e_flags;                /* Processor-specific flags */
  Elf32_Half    e_ehsize;               /* ELF header size in bytes */
  Elf32_Half    e_phentsize;            /* Program header table entry size */
  Elf32_Half    e_phnum;                /* Program header table entry count */
  Elf32_Half    e_shentsize;            /* Section header table entry size */
  Elf32_Half    e_shnum;                /* Section header table entry count */
  Elf32_Half    e_shstrndx;             /* Section header string table index */
} Elf32_Ehdr;
```

The program header(s) are there because they describe the executable parts of the ELF executable.

> The next portion of the program are
>   the ELF program headers. These
>   describe the sections of the program
>   that contain executable program code
>   to get mapped into the program address
>   space as it loads.

```
/* Program segment header.  */

typedef struct
{
  Elf32_Word    p_type;                 /* Segment type */
  Elf32_Off     p_offset;               /* Segment file offset */
  Elf32_Addr    p_vaddr;                /* Segment virtual address */
  Elf32_Addr    p_paddr;                /* Segment physical address */
  Elf32_Word    p_filesz;               /* Segment size in file */
  Elf32_Word    p_memsz;                /* Segment size in memory */
  Elf32_Word    p_flags;                /* Segment flags */
  Elf32_Word    p_align;                /* Segment alignment */
} Elf32_Phdr;
```

This is taken from [here](http://www.ouah.org/RevEng/x430.htm)

Comment: I know why they are there. I was asking why there is a program header, telling us where the headers are. If you can read the header then you already know where to look.

Comment: @eye: there's the program headers mentioned above, but also main file ELF headers, which contain references to all sub headers.  Is that the one you are talking about?

Comment: Nope there is a program header which defines a segment that covers the entire set of program headers.
Try
readelf -l /bin/ls

Comment: @eye: I can't find it an a description of the ELF format anywhere?